# Sci-fi quest/adventure book where progress was determined through clues/keys in the illustrations with red boss demon at the end?

Tags: story-identification

This was a book I borrowed from the library in the late 80s early 90s.

The fantasy picture book adventure progressed through various hostile scenes/worlds/dungeons and you were prompted to search for clues/keys/potions within the illustrations before you could turn the page (I don't recall if you were required to jump to pages of the path you chose, just to look for hidden keys/clues)

The only other details I recall are:

- The book was glossy, thin, magazine sized probably less than 30 pages long.
- The end of the book had a 'boss' red demon naked devil guy who damn terrified me – and the only way to 'destroy' him was with a weapon found within the secret/hidden illustrations of the book.

Does anyone remember the title of this book?

Comment: I also remember this but cannot remember the name.  It was very much a 'hidden object' book.  In each page you had to first find the monster then the items that would defeat it.

Answer (score 8):

I also remember this book vividly - after a bit of searching I have found [**The Ten Doors of Doom**](http://twoheadedthingies.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/ten-doors-of-doom.html)

Same size, 'find it' style of game and also has the monster at the end...

This is the fifth and last of [Puffin Books' five Fantasy Questbooks](http://fightingfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Fantasy_Questbook), not all of which were related to Fighting Fantasy. It was written by David Fickling and Perry Hinton, illustrated by Andrew Skilleter and published in 1987 (ISBN 0-14-032135-7).

The other books in the series were:

- Helmquest
- The Path of Peril
- Starflight Zero
- The Tasks of Tantalon