# Fantasy 'hidden object' picture book where you have to find keys

Tags: story-identification

It was a fantasy hidden object picture book, I believe it moved between a town to swamps and cabins scenes and I remember a dragon at the end. I believe a thing was to find keys or something, the art style was really nice. I can vividly remember there was a juggler with flaming sticks in one scene, I think all the characters were bald.

Read it around 2006 - 2008

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: You should really be asking two books as two separate questions, also when you read them would be incredibly helpful to narrow down the book. Finally, take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help add in any more details.

Comment: :) Still plan on posting the second question?

Comment: I will just a 40 min wait time to post it. till then.

Comment: Alright. I might have an answer based upon what you posted before. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be *[Dragon Quest](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0794510981)* by Andy Dixon (Author),‎ Felicity Brooks (Author),‎ and Nick Harris (Illustrator) from 2005.

[image: Dragon Quest - book cover]

> The people of Shortsville have lost all their hair due to an evil wizard's curse, and the reader can help them break the spell by solving the picture puzzles set in different scenes around town.

From [a review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RFQ1M49X404GK/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0794510981) (bolding mine):

> I love this book. I had it as a kid and me and my brothers and sisters would all sit around it looking for all the different objects. The artwork is amazing and some of the items are difficult to find so you don't just breeze through it. Each quest has several different things you have to find...for instance, the very first quest you have to search for the three other adventurers, find weapons to arm yourself with, look for the book of maps, and gather food to take along with you. **You also need to find a red key on each page** so that you can defeat the wizard later on. Then, at the bottom of the page there are bonus items to find, so you're usually looking for at least 50 objects. It's a lot of fun, and my siblings and I still enjoy this book all these years later. Even my mom was looking at it with us, so it's good for all ages.

Found via a Google search for *fantasy hidden object picture book dragon* (not my first attempt, but I don't keep track of the failed ones)

Comment: That's it, thanks mate. I've spent hours looking for it.

Comment: Similar; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47639/sci-fi-quest-adventure-book-where-progress-was-determined-through-clues-keys-in